# Como pegar imagens dentro de um post no "the loop" (wordpress)?

Tags: php, wordpress, imagem

A intenção seria fazer cards assim das ultimas postagens,
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pegando a **primeira imagem do post** isso tudo dentro de um "the loop". Pedaços do cógido que tentei, mas não funcionou:

index.php:

```
?php
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
?>
```

content.php (parte):

```
<img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(the_post()); ?>" alt="">
```

Answer (score 0):

A função [the_post_thumbnail_url](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail_url/) tem como primeiro parâmetro o **tamanho** que será a imagem, você está passando `the_post()`.

Sendo assim, você pode omitir o tamanho (e então "post-thumbnail" será utilizado), ou especificar algum outro. Além disso, o método já retorna a tag `img`:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>
```

Comment: Esse método retorna qual imagem dentro do post? Alguma com alguma tag "thumbnail" específica ou a primeira imagem do post? Tentei usar essa função mas a imagem dentro do post não foi retornada.

Comment: Então, na verdade no WordPress padrão só possui uma imagem destacada, você está utilizando algum plugin? Woocommerce talvez?